# Expected Square Distance from Origin of Random Walk in $\mathbb{Z}^2$

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

I'm trying to find the expected value of the squared distance from the origin of a simple symmetric random walk in $\mathbb{Z}^2$ at time $n$.  So far, I have calculated that if $(X,Y)$ is the position of the walker at time $n$, then this is given by $$\mathbb{E}(X^2+Y^2)=\mathbb{E}(X^2)+\mathbb{E}(Y^2)=2\mathbb{E}(X^2)=2\sum_{k=0}^{n}k^2\mathbb{P}(X=\pm k)\\ =4\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^2\mathbb{P}(X=k)$$
I tried to proceed by calculating $\mathbb{P}(X=k)$.  I get something like:
$$\mathbb{P}(X=k)=\sum_{i=k}^{n}{n \choose i}{n-i \choose i-k}.25^{2i-k}.5^{n-2i+k}$$
This doesn't seem like a feasible way to proceed.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$X = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$$
where $X_i \in \{ -1, 0, 1 \}$ is the change in $x$ at step $i$.  Since the variables $X_i$ are independent and each has mean 0, this implies that
$$E(X^2) = \sum_{i=1}^n E(X_i)^2 = n E(X_1^2)$$.
From here, it should be easy to calculate $E(X_1^2)$ explicitly.

Comment: Good point haha.

Comment: How is zero mean relevant?

Comment: @Rodrigo It's necessary for the proof of $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ independent, $E(X_i) = 0$ implies $E((\sum X_i)^2) = \sum E(X_i^2)$.  For a counterexample without this condition, consider $n=2$, $X_1 \equiv 1$, $X_2 \equiv 1$; then $E((X_1+X_2)^2) = 4 \neq 2 = E(X_1^2) + E(X_2^2)$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler You're right, of course. Lack of correlation alone does not make $ \mathbb{E} (X_1 X_2) = 0$.